# It is possible to retrieve value from activity not loaded

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

My goal is to get the text of a Textview in another Activity not using Intent to pass a variable or not loading the target Activity.
I have the Main activity with a text view (t1) and a button (b1).
I have also Activity2 with a text view (t2).
I want to get the text value of t2 and display it on the Main activity (in t1) when I tap the button (b1)...

Is it possible without using Intent or loading the second activity?

I tried:
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="138dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/b1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.527"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.138" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="68dp"
        android:text="Write Activity2's text"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.125" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView t1, t2;
    private Button b1;
    public Main2Activity two;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main);
        t1 = findViewById (R.id.t1);
        b1 = findViewById (R.id.b1);
        b1.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
            @Override
            public void onClick ( View v ) {
                String text = two.getCont ();
                t1.setText (text);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main2Activity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HELLO ANDROID"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity2.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView t2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        setContentView (R.layout.activity_main2);
        t2 = findViewById (R.id.t2);
    }
    public String getCont(){
        String name = t2.getText ().toString ();
        return name;
    }
}
```

When I debug I have this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.example.basi.Main2Activity.getCont()' on a null object reference
```

on this line:
String text = two.getCont ();

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to start the Main2Activity every time, then your other option would be to save the value in SharedPreferences or sqlite database. You can then retrieve the value in your MainActivity.

```
//retrieve the shared preferences of string, that has previously been stored
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("Main2Activity",MODE_PRIVATE);
String name = prefs.getString("strt2", "defaultstring");
```

If there is no value stored previously, then the default string would be used.

Comment: How do I get the value of t2 ( hello android)? t2.getText() not work.....
String name = prefs.getString("strt2", t2.getText());

Comment: You cannot get value from t2, because it is null. The way you are attempting to get the value will not work if activity 2 has not finished onCreate(). Use sharedpreferences, put your "hello android" as the default string: String name = prefs.getString("strt2", "hello android");